# Match a table cell class and index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is just a demonstration for the theory that I want to apply to my app so using THIS instead of td.flex is not appropriate for the the second line in the function.

Also I MUST Use .index instead of nth-child for other reasons.

That all said :)

The following function loops through all the TD's in the first row of a table that have a class of flex. For each of these record the index value. The next line is not part of the real application but to test the theory should find all the tds with a class of flex that have an index value that matches the cellIndex value. Any ideas how to get this to work?

**Remember this code is to test the theory hence why I am not using nth-child or this to apply the css colouring!**

```
cellIndex = new Array();

    $('table tr:first-child td.flex').each(function (i) {

        cellIndex[i] = $(this).index();

        $($('td.flex').index(cellIndex)).css('background-color', '#ff0000');

    });
```

if I do: `console.log($('td.flex').index(cellIndex));`

I get `-1` for each loop

**Just to confirm I know I could do this:**

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
```

but this **IS NOT** what I'm trying to achieve with this function and would NOT work in the real application.

HTML example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="flex">Flex</td>
<td>Not Flex</td>
<td class="flex">Flex</td>
<td>Not Flex</td>
<td>Not Flex</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you toss in an example of the HTML too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the each function already include an index system. So you can use it like this (cellIndex is obsolete then): http://jsfiddle.net/TMFg3/

```
cellIndex = new Array();

$('table tr:first-child td.flex').each(function (i) {

    cellIndex[i] = i;

   $('td.flex:eq('+i+')').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

});
```

If you wan't to use the cellIndex, then you have to loop it outside the each function, since you can't post an array to an index identifer, plus it would change the same targets in each loop :)

You can ofcourse also use the index in cellIndex like this:

```
cellIndex = new Array();

$('table tr:first-child td.flex').each(function (i) {

    cellIndex[i] = i;

   $('td.flex:eq('+cellIndex[i]+')').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to walk the list you could do:

```
$('table tr td:first-child td.flex').each(function (i) {        
    var cellIndex =$('table tr:first-child td').index(this);
    $('#hello').text($('#hello').text()+'"'+cellIndex+'",');
    $('td').eq(cellIndex).css('background-color', '#ff0000');    
});
```

Assumption here is that the element identified by #hello exists - it would then contain "0","2", showing the indexes, and the elements would be red background.

To put this in an array:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myCellIndexes=[];
  $('table tr td').parent().find('.flex').css('background-color','green');
  $('table tr:first-child td.flex').each(function (i) {        
    var cellIndex =$('table tr:first-child td').index(this);
    myCellIndexes[i]=cellIndex;
    $('#hello').text($('#hello').text()+'"'+cellIndex+'",');
    $('td').eq(cellIndex).css('background-color', '#ff0000');  
   }); 
   $('#hello').text($('#hello').text()+myCellIndexes);
});
```

the result would be: "0","2",0,2  in the hello at the end demonstrating that the array now holds the indexes of the elements.  This should give you a working knowlege of what you want to get your real work done :)